Understanding "smack" in C.S. Lewis's diary
When C.S. Lewis met Tolkien for the first time, he noted down in his diary: "He is a smooth, pale, fluent little chap. . . . No harm in him: only needs a smack or so." What is the meaning of "a smack" here? A loud kiss or a slap?

It's certainly not the former. Apparently, their first meeting was not a pleasant one; it has to be a slap, although I'm sure Lewis was being humorous.

Thanks, that really seems more reasonable, given the initial friction between the two.

I wondered if the sense of "smack" as "kiss" might be a recent coinage, but the OED says that's older than the sense of hit - it originally meant to make a noise with the mouth, back in the 16th century, soon applied to kissing; hit with a whip early 18th century; and hit with open hand 1835. But all long before CS Lewis.

Perhaps: “A mere tasting, a small quantity, of liquor; a mouthful. Also figurative.” —OED

@TinfoilHat You think he might have meant that it's necessary to get Tolkien a little drunk for him to be interesting?

@StuartF I'm guessing that the all the later meanings come from the fact that they make sounds similar to the one you make with the mouth.

@Barmar Good job it wasn't 'only needs a little smack'.

@Barmar — Yes, something like that. If you read the whole passage, it sounds like Lewis thinks Tolkien needs to chill.

He may have needed a smack because he was too well mannered, unaffected by mere insults. It could mean various things, ofc.

Would it be OK to either drop or explain in detail '… the initial friction between the two…'? I ask because you seem to be adding - or rather, hinting at - info not part of the Question which to me would be bad for a mere commentator, and seems unreasonable from the inquisitor.

@StuartF Once you go East of France, most of Europe uses something sounding like 'smack' to mean not 'kiss' but 'taste' which I suggest goes back long before the 16th century.
Other details are available, but hardly useful here…

The meaning of 'a smack' there is almost certainly nothing like 'a loud kiss', nor literally 'a slap'.
It might mean '… something to wake him up…' but only idiomatically.
If Lewis had said 'he needs a slap round the back of the head' should anyone take that more, or less literally?


No harm in him: only needs a smack or so."

smack = slap. These are interchangeable in the phrase.
This seems to be British English, and is quite common.
It relates to chastising an unruly or obnoxious child in the hopes of improving its behaviour.
However, when used of someone that you would not strike (and in such context as we are given) and to use another idiom, it is the equivalent of "needs taking down a peg or two" to indicate that the subject (Tolkien) is probably over self-confident.
There are a slew of phrases based on this model:
He needs a smack round the head with a wet fish/with something heavy, etc.
I'm genuinely surprised that Google Books have no mention but Google give the following for a search for ""needs a slap/smack". I have excluded actual smacking/slapping and use the phrase only figuratively.

Reddit:
Who's the bloke in the Asda adverts? MadJen1979. Annoying!
Needs a slap round the head with a kipper.


Graffiti = lame?
MMO-Champion https://www.mmo-champion.com › ... › General Off-Topic 6
Nov 2011 — But Yeah Graffiti can be an art, a 15 year old running
tagging is just a **** that needs a slap round the head. ... needs a slap round the head.


Army Rumour Service https://www.arrse.co.uk › ... › The NAAFI Bar 19
Jun 2015 — There's a gay orange bloke on UTV who needs a slap round
the head with a big feckorf spanner.


The GAA Discussion Board http://gaaboard.com › board 12 Mar 2008 —
Stupid unnecessary waste of money. Whoever dreamt this one up needs a
slap round the head.


Wow, 3rd tri. This chick's friend needs a smack. - Community The Bump
https://forums.thebump.com › discussion › wow-3rd-tri-t... 24 Sept
2009 — Re: Wow, 3rd tri. This chick's friend needs a smack. ... Yeah,
that person would no longer be my friend. TACKY! ... Wow. That is so
beyond tacky.


Planet Platonic (or why Chris Carter needs a smack to the ... Medium ·
Angela Misri 5 likes · 8 years ago Planet Platonic (or why Chris
Carter needs a smack to the back of his head).


TikTok https://www.tiktok.com › video TikTok video from Dustin Brohm
(@massiveagent): “The real estate industry needs a smack across the
face to wake up. ‍I volunteer to do the smacking”.


smack is not British English.  Any AmE speaker of similar ilk might say the exact same thing.

@Lambie (i) I said it "seemed to be" - based on the comments above by AE speakers - they are miles off. (ii) It is definitely used in BE - you should know that.... It might, in some parts of the US be understood and even used, but in others, apparently not.

Those speakers are misguided. I know it is used in BrE but when words are used on both sides of the pond, I don't find it necessary to constantly be saying it. Only those are not.

@Lambie "I don't find it necessary to constantly be saying it." I hope there are other phrases that you do not feel the need to repeat.

Just to highlight how smack probably means slap (as in, taking Tolkien down a peg), here is the extended text in his diary (Tuesday 11 May; p. 392-3 of All My Road Before Me: The Diary of C.S. Lewis 1922-1927, edited by Walter Hooper, Harcourt Brace, 1991). Basically, he describes an "English tea" or faculty meeting where people bring up ideas; after this meeting, he had a chat with Tolkien:

In to Merton for the "English tea" at 4. Here there was hardly any talk of the strike. Discussion turned on Fletcher's proposal to co-ordinate the lecture list with the ordinary course of tutorial work. Everyone agreed, tho' Gordon spoke of the danger of making the thing too much of "an easily running engine that can give no pleasure to anyone except the engineer". Miss Lee talked a lot of nonsense about the need for lessons in pronunciation and beginners' "outlines of literature".
Tolkien managed to get the discussion round to the proposed English Prelim. I had a talk with him afterwards. He is a smooth, pale, fluent little chap -- can't read Spenser because of the forms -- thinks the language is the real thing in the school -- thinks all literature is written for the amusement of men between thirty and forty -- we ought to vote ourselves out of existence if we were honest -- still the sound-changes and the gobbets are great fun for the dons. No harm in him: only needs a smack or so. His pet abomination is the idea of "liberal" studies. Technical hobbies are more in his line.

So Lewis's diary mention of a smack is in the context of an initial conversation with Tolkien. Lewis's attitude is not mere disdain, as he shows for the ideas of another colleague (Miss Lee is Margaret Lucy Lee). It's a more indulgent disagreement that one can read in Lewis's implied disagreement with every point:

"can't read Spenser because of the forms" - Tolkien can't take Spenser's artificial diction. Lewis loves Spenser and will write about and teach his work.
"thinks the language is the real thing in the school" - Tolkien is a linguist and on the language side; Lewis is on the literature side.
"thinks all literature is written for the amusement of men between thirty and forty" - Tolkien is dismissive of a larger audience of readership for literature; Lewis is professionally and personally committed to a broader audience for literature.
"we ought to vote ourselves out of existence if we were honest" and "still the sound-changes and the gobbets are great fun for the dons" - Tolkien believes that the study of languages (sound-changes) and literatures (gobbets or text excerpts) may be irrelevant, but keep those who teach and study it happy; Lewis likely sees greater value in what they're doing

Hence Lewis's response is as someone who disagrees with Tolkien but doesn't see an imminent threat in his ideas (it's not like they would vote themselves out of existence): "No harm in him. Only needs a smack or so." It's treating Tolkien like a diminutive pipsqueak, consistent with describing him as a "smooth, pale, fluent little chap."
